# Class Not Found Exception - Xamarin Android

Tags: java, xamarin, xamarin.android, classnotfoundexception

I get this error when I build my Xamarin.Android project.

```
06-05 12:42:15.322 I/MonoDroid(30682): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682): Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md565316a0900a9b0d8bca349e28cad6b91.AndroidVPNConnection_LaunchVPNServiceConnection" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.redcheetah-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.redcheetah-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+Types.FindClass (System.String classname) [0x00114] in <bd30a18775d94dc8b6263aecd1ca9077>:0 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at Java.Interop.JniType..ctor (System.String classname) [0x00006] in <bd30a18775d94dc8b6263aecd1ca9077>:0 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods..ctor (System.Type declaringType) [0x00064] in <bd30a18775d94dc8b6263aecd1ca9077>:0 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.GetConstructorsForType (System.Type declaringType) [0x0002c] in <bd30a18775d94dc8b6263aecd1ca9077>:0 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.StartCreateInstance (System.String constructorSignature, System.Type declaringType, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00032] in <bd30a18775d94dc8b6263aecd1ca9077>:0 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at Java.Lang.Object..ctor () [0x0001f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4695/9dbc4c53/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/android-23/mcw/Java.Lang.Object.cs:30 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at SwiftAndroidLib.AndroidVPNConnection+LaunchVPNServiceConnection..ctor (SwiftAndroidLib.AndroidVPNConnection outerInstance) [0x00000] in C:\WorkSpace\RC\ClientApp\SwiftLib\SwiftAndroidLib\AndroidVPNConnectionJavaBindingLib.cs:349 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at SwiftAndroidLib.AndroidVPNConnection..ctor () [0x00034] in C:\WorkSpace\RC\ClientApp\SwiftLib\SwiftAndroidLib\AndroidVPNConnectionJavaBindingLib.cs:39 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at SwiftCommonLib.SwiftBaseApp.RegisterPlatformSpecificServices () [0x0001e] in C:\WorkSpace\RC\ClientApp\SwiftLib\SwiftAndroidLib\SwiftAndroidApp.cs:81 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at SwiftCommonLib.SwiftBaseApp+<RegisterPlatformServices>d__15.MoveNext () [0x0007f] in C:\WorkSpace\RC\ClientApp\SwiftLib\SwiftCommonLib\SwiftBaseApp.cs:41 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at RedCheetah.RedCheetahApp+<RegisterPlatformServices>d__2.MoveNext () [0x00020] in C:\WorkSpace\RC\ClientApp\RedCheetah\RedCheetah.XFormsApp\RedCheetahApp.cs:39 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at SwiftCommonLib.SwiftBaseApp+<Init>d__14.MoveNext () [0x0002b] in C:\WorkSpace\RC\ClientApp\SwiftLib\SwiftCommonLib\SwiftBaseApp.cs:20 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1018 
06-05 12:42:15.380 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4695/9dbc4c53/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:35 
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4695/9dbc4c53/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36 
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4695/9dbc4c53/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/android-23/mcw/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:81 
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:1b051e2f-3dbb-406a-ba95-3384e34e8ded (intptr,intptr)
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):   --- End of managed Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException stack trace ---
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md565316a0900a9b0d8bca349e28cad6b91.AndroidVPNConnection_LaunchVPNServiceConnection" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.redcheetah-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.redcheetah-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):  at md53843fcbd823548032cdc16788941cea6.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):  at md53843fcbd823548032cdc16788941cea6.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2467)
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2594)
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:177)
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1469)
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5627)
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):  Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: md565316a0900a9b0d8bca349e28cad6b91.AndroidVPNConnection_LaunchVPNServiceConnection
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):      ... 16 more
06-05 12:42:15.381 I/MonoDroid(30682):  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
06-05 12:42:15.394 D/Mono    (30682): Assembly Ref addref HockeySDK.AndroidBindings[0xb46eba60] -> System[0x9c9daee0]: 10
```

I have tried the following things:

- Reinstall Xamarin
- Cleaned and Rebuilt the solution (Builds successfully)
- I also enabled Diagnostic output in MSBuild.

Please, How do I fix this error?

Comment: Are you building & deploying a proguard built app? Are you using that class in some way? Doing anything with VPN connections?

Comment: Yes I am using the class and yes, I'm trying to setup a VPN connection with the app. I'm deploying not using proguard yet. I'm debugging from my android phone.

Comment: And the class is part of android or a library? I don't find any information about it online.

Comment: The class is part of a library

Comment: Did you create a Xamarin Android Binding yourself, or did you add it as a library too. It seems the Xamarin Android Binding of it is corrupt and not properly including the .jar which contains the class you're trying to (indirectly) reference.

Comment: I created a xamarin binding project myself from a ".aar" file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145912/discussion-between-user2721794-and-woellij).

Comment: I'm afraid i don't have experience with .aar bindings. Did you follow the guide at [xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/) ? It seems to have many possible  stumbling block (e.g. "set the Target Framework to the API level that the .AAR expects", or that more than one .aar cannot be included etc.) Also see their [troubleshooting steps](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/)

Answer (score 0):

Issue Fixed, I needed to inherit Java.Lang.Oject in my CSharp class i.e the class being refereed to in my error message. I needed to do this because my class also inherited from some Java based Lib.